# How to share/copy Grease P. materials from one Collection item to another? (2.80)

Tags: grease-pencil

How to share/copy Grease P. materials from one Collection item to another? (2.80).

There must be a way!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that copying a layer from one object to another also allows you to import all the materials present on that layer. Maybe it can help.

[image]